# How to validate increased performance using by Centralized Cache Management in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

(On Single machine)
I installed Hadoop 2.4.1. And write a program for read a sequence file with 28.6 MB, Iterate this program 10,000 time.
Then Get result:

```
    Without  Centralized Cache
    Run              Time(in ms)
    1                19840
    2                15096
    3                14091
    4                14222
    5                14576


    With Centralized Cache
    Run              Time(in ms)
    1                19158
    2                14649
    3                14461
    4                14302
    5                14715
```

And I also write a Map-reduce Job and iterate it 25 times
Result:

```
    Without  Centralized Cache
    Run              Time(in ms)
    1                909265
    2                922750
    3                898311


    With Centralized Cache
    Run              Time(in ms)
    1                898550
    2                897663
    3                926033
```

Not found Main difference between performance using Centralized Cache and without.
How to Analysis Increase performance using Centralized Cache?
Suggest any other way to find Increase performance using Centralized Cache.